# Checking my knowledge about WinHTTP and HTTP Server API roles and purposes

Tags: .net, wcf, http, service, communication

I am starting to write services with WCF by Microsoft and just got into something called `WinHTTP` and `HTTP Server`.

Well, at the beginning I really didn't understand what they were meant for, now I start realizing that they are powerful tools, especially regarding http bound services in WCF.

I have these questions:

1) WinHTTP, I suppose it to be an application or better a collection of functions for programmers (API) in order to manage HTTP requests and replies.

2) HTTP Server is an application that enables a program to communicate with toher programs, over a network, using the http protocol WITHOUT NECESSARLY USING IIS.

3) If 2) is correct... then I assume that a service can listen for http incoming requests even on ports different from 80.

4) HTTP Server is able to manage multiple services listening for incoming http requests on the same port.

Are 1) 2) 3) 4) true?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

WCF service by definition is Web Service(but much more than that), sometimes described as Web Service on steroids.

WCF can be hosted by IIS or independent (both ways have their advantages).

WCF is highly configurable so port number is just one the things which can be configured.

It can manage multiple service, best practice for WCF recommends not to have more than 10 public functions in one service.